# WCF Service to authenticate users (.NET Membership)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership

I've had a look around on this subject most of the afternoon and still haven't seen a standard way of doing this.

I'm literally wanting a WCF service that connects to a .NET Membership system to be readily available to be called by a .NET site (could be more than one, thus the service) - should be easy enough, right? So...

.NET Site ----> WCF Service (Authenticate against .NET Membership) ----> .NET Site

I've set my SSL up on IIS, and I'm fully aware of WCF / .NET Membership, but my issue is linking the WCF service to the client site, how they're actually aware of each other and how the WCF service recognizes the Membership service?

I've looked at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx

Which goes through the process of what I thought I was after - yet no connection strings are really made in that example, or any reference to the actual membership table. Further more, there's no example of how the client site is then authorised by the service.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "NET Site".  What is "client site".   Please be more specific.   The WCF Service is membership aware if it is hosted in an ASP.NET Web Site (or application) that has membership services.  Did you follow the link at the top of the link in you question on how to configure membership?

Comment: Apologies, "client site" is my terminology for ".net site" - the overall site that requires authentication that will gain this authentication from the WCF service.I want this service to be completely stand-alone as to be accessed by one or more sites.

Comment: The whole tutorial was buried in there, completely missed it after 3/4 hours of looking around there. Upvoted your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case my comment was the answer will post it as an answer.

The Web Site that hosts Service must implement membership services.

[Configuring an ASP.NET Application to Use Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx)